# bs4 getting only first 15 values

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Hi am new to Bs4 i need to get all the product from a site i tried to get the values but it shows only first 15 from a 100 product in a page

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
base_url = 'http://www.elkay.com/sinks/undermount#q=|100|0|1|'
response = requests.get(base_url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content.decode('utf-8'), "html.parser")

is_row = soup.findAll('div', attrs={'class': 'product result_detail'})
print(is_row)
```

Can any One help me ?

here is_row is a ResultSet with len-15 actually their is 100 products

Any Help would be appriciated. Thanks

Comment: why have you deleted [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72564197/16343464)?

Comment: Accicendtly deleted . Your solution work fine.. thank you.Try to add a comment accidently deleted question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check that URL with a 'not-that-fast' connection (like mine :D) you can see that it only loads 15 items, AFTER it is fully loaded it sends ANOTHER request to load the rest of the items. This is why you only get the first 15 items using your code (you only get the response for the first request)

Using Chrome Developer Tools (press F12) you can easily find the right request to make:

1. Open the site
2. Open developer tools (F12)
3. Click on the Network tab
4. Now select Results per page: 100
5. You should see a new request called CategoryNavigationResultsView
6. Copy the curl command (Copy as cURL (bash))

[image: Copy curl command]

7. Use [this very handy site](https://curl.trillworks.com/#python) to convert the curl request into python requests

I won't copy the full request but it has a data param:

```
data = {
    'contentBeginIndex': '0^',
    'productBeginIndex': '0^',
    'showPageSize': '100^',
}
```

Sending the request like this should get you all 100 items. You can also get the following pages by changing the ...BeginIndex.

Comment: I got the link request from the above. How can I call that. I just need to replace my url or want to do something else.

Comment: How can I apply the cookies and url into my program mentioned in the above

Comment: The site mentioned in step 7 gives you python code. If you copy it into a .py file and run it it should work. In your case headers and cookies might be unnecessary (you have to play around with it), so the request call will look something like this: `response = requests.post('http://www.elkay.com/CategoryNavigationResultsView', params=params, data=data)`

Comment: When I try to read the content. Soup(response.content,"html.parser") it's how's an error that values of the parameter Lang I'd is not correct

Comment: Can you help me to read the content and edit my code is it possible?

Comment: I also got the same error with langId. In step 6 if I choose Copy as cURL (**bash**) and copy this to the site in step 7 it gives you slighty different python code which should work. Can you please confirm? (I also edited my answer)

Comment: Ok let me check