# group the data as continuous block pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I had a panda DataFrame looks like

```
   start end
0  10    20
1  30    35
2  20    25
3  35    40
4  40    45
5  60    70
6  70    80
```

Expecting Output like

```
[{"start":10,"end":25},{"start":30,"end":45},{"start":60,"end":80}]
```

The output is calculated based on start from min of start and check the end value have any other start and take it and go continue check

Comment: This isn't too bad. But can you have instances where the start of one isn't the stop of another? I.e. 10-20 and another 18-25 that you would want to combine into 10-25? That case is a lot trickier

Comment: This is a network problem, consider [networkx](https://networkx.org/).

Comment: @Quang you can actually solve this with pandas, this is more an overlapping interval problem ;)

Comment: May be. for now you can consider like there is nothing like that

Comment: @ALollz the overlapping interval is not so hard to solve either ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can compute a group on the sorted items and convert [`to_dict`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html):

```
df2 = df.sort_values(by=['start', 'end'])

group = df2['start'].ne(df2['end'].shift()).cumsum()
# or if overlapping
# group = df2['start'].gt(df2['end'].shift()).cumsum()

out = df2.groupby(group).agg({'start': 'min', 'end': 'max'}).to_dict('records')
```

output:

```
[{'start': 10, 'end': 25}, {'start': 30, 'end': 45}, {'start': 60, 'end': 80}]
```

##### overlapping

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'start': [10, 30, 18, 35, 40, 60, 70], 'end': [20, 35, 25, 40, 45, 70, 80]})

df2 = df.sort_values(by=['start', 'end'])
group = df2['start'].gt(df2['end'].shift()).cumsum()
df2.groupby(group).agg({'start': 'min', 'end': 'max'}).to_dict('records')
```